# Formtastic radio collection with hints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, formtastic

I am working with Active Admin to create a form which has a radio collection.

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Options" do
    f.input :type, as: :radio, collection: Types.all.map{|type| [type.name, type.name]}
  end
end
```

I want to add a hint to each option in the radio collection. (A hint similar to a string input or various others).

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score -2):

I would do it this way:

```
f.input :type, as: :radio, collection: Type.pluck(:name)
```

the method `pluck` is same as doing `Type.all.map(&:name)`

see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck for more info.

Comment: This answer does in no way help to solve the problem on how to display hint with each option